# How to constrain a product to one shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, catalog, shipment

A client of mine sells some products that can not be shipped via regular channels due to extreme size and/or weight.

For these products, I would like to add a setting like "can be shipped regularly".
Then, in the checkout process I would like to check if there are any products in the cart having this flag, and if so: only show the shipment option "delivery on appointment".

I have already developed custom shipment carriers/methods, but do not know what would be a good way to disable any shipment methods for carts that contain a product matching the criteria.

I expected that when I set `<sort_order>99999</sort_order>` in the carrier's `config.xml` (so it's rendered last) and then having the following code in the `Carrier.php` model, I would be able to unset any other possible carriers. However, this does not work.

```
<?php
class Vendor_ExampleCarrier_Model_Carrier
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    /** @var string carrier code */
    protected $_code = 'vendor_examplecarrier';

    /**
     * Collect and get rates
     * 
     * @param  Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
     * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result|bool|null
     */
    public function collectRates( Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request )
    {
        // ...
        $canShipRegularly = false;
        // ...

        $shippingRateResultModel = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        if (true !== $canShipRegularly) {
            // does nothing
            $shippingRatesResultModel->reset();

            // returns empty array
            $shippingRatesResultModel->getAllRates();
        }

        return $shippingRateResultModel;
    }

    // other stuff..
}
```

I feel this might be a possible solution, if I would be possible to get access to this model in another scope.

Anyone have an idea as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the Magento `table rates` shipping method. By limiting the weight for the `table rate` rules they won't show up if an item is added with sufficient weight to invalidate the rule.

You could also make the weight of the over sized products *9999* for example. This way there is a clear difference between shippable products and over sized products.

Then add the **appointment** method either as different shipping method or separate rule in table rates and you should be good to go

Comment: Also should be noted there are several extensions to deal with this situation.  Most notably Amasty and webshopapps